# Winui TabView change tab view model (and layout) depending on tab type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, winui-3, winui

I have a tab view and multiple viewmodels which the tab view can display, each tab can be a type of say ViewModel1 and ViewModel2, they will also have their own layout depending on the type of model it is. The issue I am facing is that I cannot get the view to change and load the correct model, it WPF this was fairly straight forward I could write something like the below for data template and it would render the correct view:

```
<TabControl.Resources><DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tab:ViewModel}">

    </DataTemplate>
    
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tab:ViewModel2}">
    
    </DataTemplate>

</TabControl.Resources>
```

However, with winui I x:Type is no longer available, and I am struggling to figure out a way of dynamically changing the view and model.

Current I have an interface called ITab, this interface stores the TabName and the TabType (Model1 or 2)

```
string Name { get; set; } 
TabType TabType { get; }
```

Any viewmodel which wants to be part of the tab collection, must implement this interface. In the parent viewmodel I then have an observable collection of ITab, this is bind to the Tabs ItemsSource.

In the XAML I have this code here, (some of this will copied from an old WPF project)

```
<TabView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Model1" x:Key="model1">
        <Grid> <!--VIEW FOR MODEL 1--> </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Model1" x:Key="model2"> <!--VIEW FOR MODEL 2--> </DataTemplate>
</TabView.Resources>

<TabView.TabItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="itab:ITab">
        <TabViewItem Header="{Binding Name}">
            <TextBlock>Text</TextBlock>
        </TabViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabView.TabItemTemplate>
```

This renders the tab and display the tab name, however, this only happens for one viewmodel, how do I specify to use Model2 if the tabtype is Model2 else Model1?

I did try making a custom TabItemTemplateSelector

```
<TabView.TabItems>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="itab:ITab">
        <TabViewItem Header="{Binding Name}">
            <templates:TabItemTemplateSelector Model1="{StaticResource model1}" Model2="{StaticResource model2}" />
        </TabViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabView.TabItems>
```

```
public class TabItemTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector { private DataTemplate _model1; private DataTemplate _model2;

    public DataTemplate Model1
    {
        get { return _model1; }
        set { _model1 = value; }
    }
    
    public DataTemplate Model2
    {
        get { return _model2; }
        set { _model2 = value; }
    }
    
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            var tab = (ITab)item;
    
            switch (tab.TabType)
            {
                case TabType.Model1:
                    return _model1;
                case TabType.Model2:
                    return _model2;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Uknown tab type");
            }
        }
    
        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
    
    }
```

However, when this is rendered it displays the class name e.g. MyApp.Models.TabItemSelector

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74379247/selecting-a-data-template-based-on-type-in-uwp/74387341#74387341). `<templates:TabItemTemplateSelector Model1="{S...` should be used as TabView Property [TabView.TabItemTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tabview.tabitemtemplateselector?view=windows-app-sdk-1.3), instead of in `DataTemplate`.

So you need to define DataTemplateSelector resources in the upper level container of TabView, use `TabItemTemplateSelector` to use the DataTemplateSelector.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Model1" x:Key="model1">
            <Grid>
                <!--VIEW FOR MODEL 1-->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Model1" x:Key="model2">
            <!--VIEW FOR MODEL 2-->
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:TabItemTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector" Model1="{StaticResource model1}" Model2="{StaticResource model2}" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <TabView TabItemsSource="{x:Bind TabList}" TabItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}">
        
    </TabView>
    
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks, I added the data template to the page resources top level and bound as property to the TabView, this has resulted in a really weird nested tab issue, which is explained here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758874/using-tabitemtemplateselector-in-winui-3-in-conjunction-with-a-templateselector This seems like a bug, do you know of a workaround? Thought it would have been fixed as that post was made 2 years ago

Comment: There is no other solution yet, you can refer to the method in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758874/using-tabitemtemplateselector-in-winui-3-in-conjunction-with-a-templateselector), use a custom TabViewItem. You can submit this unexpected behavior through the [Feedback Hub](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332), or submit it in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues), and I will also report this unexpected behavior through internal channels.